# JavaScript - Assigning Array Index to Return Value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, date

I am trying to assign a return value to an element in an array, and for some reason it is overwriting both elements in the array to the same value instead of just the second element.

The datepicker I'm using for this can be found here, for reference.

http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/

```
function AddDays(date, days)
{
  var newDate = new Date(date.setTime( date.getTime() + days * 86400000 ));
  return newDate;
}

$('#nights').on('change', function(){
  var $dp = $('#date');
  var t = $dp.DatePickerGetDate();
  console.log(t);  // Output 1
  t[1] = AddDays(t[0], $(this).val());
  console.log(t); // Output 2
});
```

Output 1 : [Mon Jan 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), Sun Jan 08 2017 23:59:59 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)]

Output 2 : [Mon Jan 09 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), Mon Jan 09 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)]

As you can see, when I try to assign the second element `t[1]` to equal the return of `AddDays(t[0], $(this).val())` both dates get set the same exact date. However, the second element is supposed to be equal to the first element plus the number of days specified.

I also verified that the element `$(this).val()` is not zero.  In my case that is in fact returning 7 when I run `console.log($(this).val());` right before the assignment of `t[1]`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you create a working example?

Comment: You're mutating the original date before passing it to the `Date` constructor, so naturally they'll end up with the same time. Drop the `d.setTime()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function modifies the date that is passed in when you call `setTime`. You can remove the call to `setTime` to solve your problem.

```
function addDays(date, days) {
  return new Date(date.getTime() + (days * 86400000));
}
```

Or make a brand new date object and call `setDate` or `setTime` on the copy.

```
function addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: This was in fact the answer that worked for me. Thanks. Worked like a charm.